# Benchmark of OpenMP in C

Tags: c, openmp, benchmarking

I'm looking for a benchmark of OpenMP in C. Just a simple (useless) task that shows that this technique really works.
Something like:

```
#include <omp.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#define NULL 0
int main ()
{
    int i, j;

    long long int to_usec(struct timeval t)
    {
        return t.tv_sec*1000000LL + t.tv_usec;
    }
    struct timeval s_time, e_time;
    gettimeofday(&s_time, NULL);

    // long lasting code...
    #pragma omp parallel for
    for(i=0; i<100000; i++)
    {
        // ...
    }

    gettimeofday(&e_time, NULL);
    printf("total time [ms]: %lld\n", (to_usec(e_time) - to_usec(s_time)) / (1000));
}
```

Does anybody have an idea?

Comment: Since you're (probably) using Linux, you can delegate the timing code to the `time` command and just have a loop that e.g. takes an integer and decides if it prime or not (from 1 to, say, 100 million to begin with).

Comment: Would you mind to show me some code? Maybe as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

As a trivial benchmark one can use data parallel operations on the arrays.  For example:

```
double a[N], b[N], c[N];

/* initialize arrays A and B with some data. */
init (a, b);

#pragma omp parallel for
for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
    c[i] = a[i] * b[i] + 1;
```

By adjusting N and the complexity of the inner operation you will be able to see the effect very quickly.  (You might need to allocate your arrays on heap rather than on stack)

Comment: You'll want a more complex inner operation else you might be memory bound (and hence throwing more threads at the problem will not help beyond a point).

Comment: It is surely memory bound and in in theory you are right, however, keep in mind that it is a massively data parallel operation.  So you can only exhaust your memory bus if all the cores are doing memory operations.  That suggests that if you have more than one core, you will see an effect of using openmp,as there is no communication involved.  Here are some: [link to the experiment](https://gist.github.com/ashinkarov/7514226)

Answer (score 0):

When it comes to benchmarks, the OpenMP ARB site provides [links to some](http://openmp.org/wp/resources/#Benchmarks). The EPCC OpenMP microbenchmarks are of particular interest since they measure implementation's overhead for each construct. One could also use the OpenMP-enabled [STREAM benchmark](http://www.cs.virginia.edu/stream/ref.html) to see how memory bandwidth scales with the number of threads. STREAM is a particularly simple benchmark - just a bunch of loops and very easy to understand.